# Groupby and selectMany and orderby doesn't bring back the data I need

Tags: c#

I have two List row1 and row2.This is data for row1:[image]

and data for row2:[image]

I Concatenate these two lists into one :

```
 var rows = rows1.Concat(rows2).ToList();
```

The result would be this:[image]
and then want to groupBy on a few fields and order by with other fields.and do some changes to some data. This is my Code

```
  var results = rows.GroupBy(row => new { row.FromBayPanel, row.TagNo })
                    .SelectMany(g => g.OrderBy(row => row.RowNo)
                    .Select((x, i) =>
                        new
                        {
                          TagGroup = x.TagGroup,
                          RowNo = (i == 0) ? (j++).ToString() : "",
                          TagNo = (i == 0) ? x.TagNo.ToString() : "",
                          FromBayPanel = x.FromBayPanel,                                                                           
                          totalItem = x.totalItem
                        }).ToList());
```

which brings me back this result:[image]

This is not what I really want I want to have this result. I Want all data with same "FromBayPanel" be listed together.
which part of my code is wrong?

Comment: Rather than showing hard-to-read screenshots, it would be *much* easier to help you if you'd show a short but complete example demonstrating the problem. (It's unlikely that you need that many properties in your data to demonstrate the problem, either...) You also haven't shown the result you *do* want...

Comment: Using `SelectMany` you flatten the grouping you did before. Thus whilst you gropued the data before `SelectMany` will remove this grouping

Comment: Do you want every group to be order by `RowNo`?

Answer (score 0):

I think when you want to order the elements within your group you have to use a different approach as `SelectMany` will simply flatten your grouped items into one single list. Thus instead of `rows.GroupBy(row => new { row.FromBayPanel, row.TagNo }).SelectMany(g => g.OrderBy(row => row.RowNo)` you may use this:

```
rows.OrderBy(x => x.FromBayPanel).ThenBy(x => x.TagNo) // this preserves the actual group-condition
         .ThenBy(x => x.RowNo) // here you order the items of every item within the group by its RowNo
         .GroupBy(row => new { row.FromBayPanel, row.TagNo })
         .Select(...)
```

EDIT: You have to make your select WITHIN every group, not afterwards:

```
rows.GroupBy(row => new { row.FromBayPanel, row.TagNo })
         .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, 
             x => x.OrderBy(y => y.RowNo)
                 .Select((y, i) =>
                 new
                 {
                     TagGroup = y.TagGroup,
                     RowNo = (i == 0) ? (j++).ToString() : "",
                     TagNo = (i == 0) ? y.TagNo.ToString() : "",
                     FromBayPanel = x.FromBayPanel,                                                              
                     totalItem = y.totalItem
                 })
         )
```

EDIT: Test see [here](http://ideone.com/5iii4A#)

Comment: it didn't worked out, it returned 8 records and and those records where not grouped and sorted FromBayPanel as I wanted

Comment: @nnmmss Sorry, I had the wrong counter-variables, replaced the `x` by `y` within the last `Select`-statement.

Comment: it didn't work out again, no success, have you tested it yourself?

Comment: @nnmmss I added a test-case